# Ag Grid : oncellClicked event is applying for other cells in the same row

Tags: angular6, ag-grid

I am using ag grid for table view in my project(angular 6).I used on cell clicked event (cellClicked).It was working ,my problem is that it is applying for entire row cells.I also used this one : [suppressRowClickSelection]="true".but it was not working.I don't want the other cells in the row not to be triggered.

Comment: `cellClicked` will be fired irrespective of `suppressRowClickSelection`'s value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comment, `cellClicked` will be fired irrespective of `suppressRowClickSelection`'s value.

If you'd like to handle `cellClicked` event only for some specific column, you have to manage it yourself.

Apply a check in `cellClicked` handler as below.

```
onCellClicked: (params) => {
    if (params.colDef.field === '') {
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```